# Sign a jar file created with maven-assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, jar-signing

I'd like to build an assembly and then sign it. My problem is that the jarsigner signs not the assembly, only the standalone jar file. Could you tell me what is the problem? Maven seems like 'magic' to me after having used Ant for years.. I can't see the way the plugins cooperate and pass information to each other.

After executing `mvn install`, I get two jar files, one called `example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and this is signed, and one called `example-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` and this is not signed. I do not need the solo one, only the assembly, but that signed.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <keystore>${project.basedir}\keystore\mykeystore</keystore>
                    <alias>myalias</alias>
                    <storepass>...</storepass>
                    <keypass>...</keypass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-my-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.FooBar</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to put the maven-assembly-plugin into the prepare-package phase instead of the package phase:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-my-assembly</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Comment: I made this change and since then I get the error saying `Embedded error: The source must not be a directory.`

Comment: Can you post the complete output to pastebin or something similar?

Comment: The plugins works. I suppose your configuration is likely wrong...

Answer (score 6):

```
    <configuration>
        <archiveDirectory>${project.build.directory}</archiveDirectory>
        <includes>
           <include>*.jar</include>
        </includes>
        <keystore>${project.basedir}/keystore/mykeystore</keystore>
        <alias>keyalias</alias>
        <storepass>storepass</storepass>
        <keypass>keypass</keypass>
    </configuration>
```

Refer this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/sign-mojo.html

Answer (score 3):

Change order of plugins in your POM. Order is relevant in Maven. Run `mvn install` again and review output log. You should be able to see the order of actions from the log.

Comment: changing the order of the plugins works! jar signing should be at the last!