# Maven Jarsigning using keystore

Tags: maven-2, m2e, jar-signing

Have found `maven` to use hard for simple things like `jar-signing`..May be I am doing this in wrong way,Correct me.

I have genereated a `keystore` file and it is located in my `src/main/keystore/mykey.keystore`...

My POM looks like :

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>   
        <executions>
        <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>sign</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
        <keystore>src/main/keystore/mykey.keystore</keystore>
        <alias>aliasname</alias>
        <storepass>password</storepass>         
    </configuration>        
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>      
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>       
    <configuration>                         
       <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
       </descriptorRefs>           
     <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
     </configuration>
    </execution>     
  </executions>      
</plugin>
```

when i run `mvn:install`  ..

```
 Executing: cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\..  
 \bin\jarsigner.exe" -verify S:\Test-API\testapplet\target\appletbio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
 [info] jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)
 [INFO] jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:    
 META-INF/maven/
```

...

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:sign 
 (default) on project
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh..It was simple..I need to use

```
   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
```

instead of

```
    <phase>package</phase>
```

This [SO Anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384704/sign-a-jar-file-created-with-maven-assembly-plugin)